# Corrupted graphics on Kubuntu 14.04 under VMware

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, vmware

After updating my Kubuntu 13.10 VM to 14.04, there is some graphics corruption. The image seems to repeat horizontally every 800 pixels:

[image]

I have tried:

- using a different guest resolution
- disabling "Accelerate 3D graphics" in the VM settings
- disabling desktop effects in the guest
- rebooting the host
- updating the host's graphics drivers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with xubuntu. It works if I use a `Linux 3.13.0-27 Kernel`, with a newer one I have that problem.

Comment: Why the downvote? Using an older kernel fixed it, thank you! The problem is present with 3.13.0-29-generic but not 3.13.0-27-generic.