# Lubuntu: my screen needs a serious reset

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, display, vmware, custom-distributions

I am building my own custom Lubuntu (based on lubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso) system image under VMware 8. It works fine, except the system a nasty tendency of screwing up the display **IF** I relogin during the same VM session. That is, when I login initially as Everybody (normal user), the display is perfect. When I logout and immediately relogin as TheAdmin, this is the result:

[image]

The order of who logs in first is immaterial.  I'm not a newbie and have been successfully using this setup (i.e. Windows+VMWare) for other Linux remastering efforts (Slax/ZenWalk/PCLinuxOS) for many years, but I need a little help with this one. Essentially is there a way to force the video driver to reset itself without restarting Linux itself? The actual VMware display driver (according to Synaptic) hasn't changed, so I don't think that an upgrade caused this either. Googling returns lots of search results about installation errors+uninstalling display drivers, but nothing close to what I'm experiencing. Thanx.

Comment: This looks exactly like the screenshot in [Corrupted graphics on Kubuntu 14.04 under VMware](http://askubuntu.com/questions/484840/corrupted-graphics-on-kubuntu-14-04-under-vmware) even though your OS is based on Lubuntu 14.04. I have a link to another question with another VMware screenshot like this, if the first link (the answer in the first link talks about a kernel version issue) doesn't help.

Comment: Have already considered the downgrade path and it won't help me.  In my case, I reinstalled and didn't take the kernel upgrade for now, but no joy...

Comment: It's the same story with the other link: [14.04 Bizarre GUI repeat behavior](http://askubuntu.com/questions/484729/14-04-bizarre-gui-repeat-behavior).

Comment: VMWare is a company, which software are you using Player, Workstation, Fusion, etc?

Comment: Sorry, Workstation 9.03 under XP SP3.